# Does in the process of profiling j profiler offline do we still be needing GUI in the process?

Tags: profiling, offline, jprofiler

if we use the offline profiling (using profiling API's, config files , triggers and all) and not use the GUI , will we still be needing GUI in the process of offline profiling. If not then does that mean that we can tunnel it into an ssh client and our analyzation observation will be drawn and shown there itself ie we do not need the GUI henceforth, or is it mandatory to use jprofiler GUI for this :  However, offline profiling still requires some actions to be performed. At least one snapshot has to be saved, otherwise no profiling data will be available for*** analysis later on***. Also, to see CPU or allocation data, you have to start recording at some point. Similarly, if you wish to be able to use the heap walker in the saved snapshot, you have to trigger a heap dump.
As mentioned on the help docs.

where does this analysis later on happen like in the GUI itself or live on the CLI while profiling offline??

further i need to know that if offline profiling is possible without the use of GUI does that mean that the observations and analyzations output will be shown live on the CLI/ssh tunnel client and if so does this mean that we do not need the licensed key which is otherwise required for GUI interactions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jpexport command line tool to extract data from a JProfiler snapshot. This is part of the full JProfiler installation, but it is a command line tool, so no GUI has to be displayed.

See

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/commandLine/snapshotExecutables.html

for more information.